# capturing pid that is changing frequently

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I am having an application that initiates several child processes, and these child processes keeps on changing all the time. I want to write a script to capture all such child processes and calculate the total memory and cpu usage. Any suggestions on how i can calculate the total/average Cpu and memory utilization?

Note: Each of the child processes don't have a standard start and stop time and they keep on changing frequently.

Comment: Hi Akhan, how do you spawn new processes? Is is a C/Python/Bash/Perl application?

Comment: it is a java based application

Comment: akhan, more information would help us to help you :)

how do you shell the external process? Do you use processbuilder? or what?

Comment: hi  Maurizio, the process that is generated is reflected as PID in a linux host machine on which the application is deployed. i wanted to know how to capture these pid's which are changing over time and continuously.  1.JBOSS- Java Application server makes a request per thread and which corresponds to shell script to create one thread. We can capture java cpu utilization as single pid present . But In case of shell script , each request dynamically generated one new thread and there are 8-10 threads which consume memory for each.

Comment: Hi Akhan, thanks for the information. When you say 8-10 threads, I guess you refer to 8-10 different processes on Linux machine having each its own PIDs. Are my assumptions correct?

Comment: Do you want to write *kernel code* for you purpose? Otherwise, why "linux-kernel" tag is used?

Comment: yes Maurizio, they are 8-10 independent process in linux machine.

Comment: the tag linux-kernel has been  removed. it was done by mistake Tsyvarev